# this.xxx.emit() is not able to communicate with Parent component in Angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-template

Hello Fellow Programmers,
I am new to Angular 4 . I am stuck with a typical case of child-parent interaction in Angular 4. I have the a child component(uw-post-feed.component) and parent component(uw-board-page.component), where I am emitting some data which my parent should listen , I have defined a simple function with a console.log for my parent to listen , my console doesn't shows any error but the parent component is not listening to what child component is throwing at it.
MY child component looks likes this.

These are my steps:

1. Importing the Output and Event Emitter

`import { Component, Output, EventEmitter, OnInit } from '@angular/core';`

uw-post-feed.component.html(child component) looks like this

```
<button (click) = "hitIT()">test button</button>
```

2. Defining the Output decorator in uw-post-feed.component.ts(child component typescript file):

export class UwPostFeedComponent extends FrPostFeedComponent implements OnInit {

```
  @Output() pullExtraPosts:EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter<string>();

  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  hitIT(){
 console.log('reacxhed');
 this.pullExtraPosts.emit('my emitted data');
 }
}
```

3.when the button is clicked, hitIT() function is triggered.

4. In my parent component HTML file:

<`uw-post-feed (pullExtraPosts)="extraPosts($event)"></uw-post-feed>{{childEvent}}`

5. In my Parent component TS file where the action for the pullExtraPosts will take place:

   extraPosts(data): void {
   console.log('hit it');
   console.log('event', data);
   }

Now I tried debugging the code too, but for some reason the debugger is not crossing my `this.pullExtraPosts.emit('my emitted data');` possible cause for this, which is stopping the extraPosts() to be triggered could be my binding of parent and child component. Is there something which i am doing wrong in my step 4.
Any suggestion or help is welcome. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: why you put public

Comment: how do you call the `hitIT` method? And do you have the `child-component` in an `*ngFor` loop?

Comment: Hi @PierreDuc ,  i  am calling the hitIT method on the click of a button on my child component.

Comment: HI @alehn96 , i tried running the program without writing public but its stillnot hitting my extraPosts(data) in my parent component.

Comment: Please reproduce it in this example https://plnkr.co/edit/nGHSa0956IPjQ1DEcN9v?p=preview

Comment: I add a variable in parent component and the emit works fine, https://plnkr.co/edit/m66OACxuzOJOgSOiKBe8?p=preview

Comment: Hi @alehn96 , thanks for your plunkr example and I have modified the code but  it still  isn't working(my console.log in my extraPosts(data) is not showing). I have modified my question and given a detailed version of my code. I guess my child component and parent component are not able to bind for some reason.

Comment: you have same code that in plunker?

Comment: Here is the plunker of my code: https://plnkr.co/edit/ZSaZ0yi3X54q60cgO8v6?p=preview

Comment: Hi guys, apologies for not able to update this post, i was doing something wrong on my end, I was trying to listen to the emit event from a wrong component.My parent component was wrong. this issue won't be visible in plunker. It's solved now. Thanks a lot for all of your views and comments.